# Views not laying out properly for iPhone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I have laid out my `ViewControllers` in `Storyboard` using `Auto Layout`, and everything looks perfect on an iPhone 5. Now I'm testing for iPhone 4 and things are not in their correct position. For example, I placed a `UIView` at the bottom of its parent `UIView`. It's width is the screen width and its height is 100. It shows up nicely on an iPhone 5 but doesn't appear at all on an iPhone 4 (I think it's because it's drawn at the height it should for an iPhone 5 which is too far below the screen for a 4)

If I'm using Auto Layout, do I still need to make adjustments to my Views? If so, what's the point of using Auto Layout at all?

Comment: Use the weird buttons at the bottom to 'reset to suggested constraints' when you have it the way you want. xcode is pretty smart at times

Comment: @OscarApeland not sure which "weird buttons" you're referring to?

Comment: You just need to use the correct constraints. If you have a view near the bottom of the screen, it should have a spacing constraint to the bottom layout guide so it will appear the same distance from the bottom in both screen sizes.

Comment: @rdelmar and I would add the spacing constraint manually and set the distance to be the difference in screen heights?

Comment: No, you can add it in IB, and it can just have one value like 8 -- the view would then appear 8 points above the bottom of the screen in both screen sizes.

Comment: This one! http://i.imgur.com/PKXREH4.png

Comment: “what's the point of using Auto Layout at all?” Ken Ferry, creator of Auto Layout, said in a [recent interview](http://www.imore.com/debug-33-ken-ferry-auto-layout-passbook-and-understudy) that the name “Auto Layout” was a mistake. There is not really anything automatic about it, in that you still have to precisely tell the computer what you want. It’s just a more semantically meaningful way to represent to the computer the relationships between views, without having to do all the layout math yourself.

Comment: @OscarApeland This didn't workout sadly. I was hoping it would...

Comment: @rdelmar if you could provide a slightly more detailed answer I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach to make your layouts fit to retina & non retina form factors.
I am not saying these are the rules, but I follow this approach & hardly get any conflicts which is difficult to resolve.

- First & foremost : Always try to design your storyboard on non-retina form factor (I mean in your case design it on iPhone4 size & then apply retina-Form Factor & verify how it fits on iPhone5 size.).
- Definitely your view at the bottom of its parent will be having a fix constraint for "Y" position. Usually, you need to make a relative constraint. So when you show it up on iPhone4, the Y & the height might be going beyond the maximum Y axis value.
- Try checking these values for your layout in Assistant Editor like `topSpace`, `leadingSpace`, `trailingSpace`, `bottomSpace` .
- `AutoLayout` doesn't mean that it will fit to your needs, however it adjusts the component accordingly.
- In case of any warning in Storyboard, try using the help & suggestion provided like, `add missing constraint` or `adjust frame to suggested`

Storyboard will never behave in the same manner for each & every screen or view your design. You need to practise it more & more & you get to know how to add constraints.

Hope that helps.